# selecting multiple dropdown menus with import.io

Tags: web-crawler, import.io

I'm trying to use [import.io](https://import.io/) to crawl through an e-commerce site and collect various pricing information. However, the price of each product is determined by what the user has set the numerous drop downs to.

Link to the site: http://www.saxoprint.co.uk/shop/brochures

I need the crawler to go through **all** the different options and gather every possible pricing combination related to this product. I originally tried using the Chrome's web scraper add on, but discovered that multiple click actions within one page are not supported by this extension.

I think this is possible with import.io but I could be wrong. Does anyone know how to gather this data, even if it's with an alternative to import.io?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, crawling through all the different options is not possible with the import.io tool. With import you would need to associate all of these different options as inputs manually. I have had success with similar e-commerce websites by writing a python script that can cycle through all the possible options and write out that data.

Thanks,
Meg